# Convergence of a sequence defined by a sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Show that the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq2}\ln\left(  2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)
$$
is convergent and compute its value.

My progress is the following: I rewrote the expresion as follows
$$
\sum_{n\geq2}\ln\left(  2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)  =\ln\prod_{n\geq2}\left(
2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)  =\ln a_{n},
$$
where $a_{n}=\left(  2-2^{1/2}\right)  \left(  2-2^{1/3}\right)  \cdot
\ldots\cdot\left(  2-2^{1/n}\right)  $; next I tried to show that the sequence
$\left(  a_{n}\right)  $ is convergent using the sandwich theorem but I get
stuck; I just wrote that
$$
a_{n}>\left(  2-2^{1/2}\right)  \left(  2-2^{1/2}\right)  \ldots\left(
2-2^{1/2}\right)  =\left(  2-\sqrt{2}\right)  ^{n},
$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}
$, where I used the fact that the map $f\left(  x\right)  =2-2^{1/x}$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: You should first check if the question is correct.
Here $\ln{2-2^1}=\ln{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: I just changed the starting point of the series.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s false. $$\ln(2-2^{1/n})=\ln(2-e^{\ln(2)/n})=\ln(2-1-\ln{2}/n+O(n^{-2}))=-(\ln{2})/n+O(n^{-2})...$$

Answer (score 0):

I will determine the convergence of the sequence $x_n=(2-2^{\frac{1}{2}})(2-2^{\frac{1}{3}})(2-2^{\frac{1}{4}})(2-2^{\frac{1}{5}}) \dots \dots (2-2^{\frac{1}{n}})$

Note that $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=2-2^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<1$.
Hence the sequence is decreasing.

Further $x_n>0$ because each of $(2-2^{\frac{1}{n}})>0$.

Thus the sequence is decreasing and bounded below.
Thus by Monotone Convergence Theorem, it converges.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ermakoff's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErmakoffsTest.html):
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf(e^x)}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x\ln\left(2-2^{\frac{1}{e^x}}\right)}{\ln\left(  2-2^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}=\infty.$$
Hence, the series diverges.

Comment: What about the previous answer? It seams that the problem is the same with computing the limit of $(2-2^\frac{1}{2})...(2-2^\frac{1}{n})$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So, the limit is equal to infinity?

Comment: @farruhotaI think there is a mistake in your limit, because $2^\frac{1}{n}$ goes to one when $n$ goes to infinity. No?

Comment: you are right, my bad. Here is the WA [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D2+to+infty%7D+%5Cln%5Cleft(+2-2%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%5Cright)) for your reference.

Comment: It is very interesting the Ermakoff's test, I didn't heard before about this one. When I tried to test the convergence of the above series, using this test, I found that $f(x)=\ln(2-2^\frac{1}{x})$ is an increasing function, not a decreasing function as it is stated in Ermakoff's test. Am I missing something? Does the test work also for increasing function?

Comment: It is equivalent to considering the decreasing function $f(x)=-\ln(2-2^{1/x})$. So, the test will handle it too.